# Настройка ScintillaNet

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, visual-studio-2017, scintilla

Через NuGet установил ScintillaNet, в панели элементов появился соответствующий элемент и я добавил его на форму. Как теперь реализовать подсветку синтаксиса C# в данном элементе? Я читал, что какой-то xml файл надо создавать, но где его создавать, как там все прописать правильно, как наладить, чтобы работало не нашел, помогите.

Comment: Есть решение куда проще, выбор синтаксиса подсветки, цветовой палитры опционально адрес проекта https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting

Comment: Xml-файл можешь взять из NPP, а вот уж куда его девать, должно быть в доках написано.